# $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Obtain the density of $Y = |X|$.

Tags: probability

> Let $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Obtain the density of $Y = |X|$.

Thoughts:

Since a normal density with mean $0$ is symmetric about the $y$-axis, and since $|X|$ doesn't take on negative values, its density is identical to the density of $X$, but multiplied by a factor of $2$ so that $ \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{|X|}(x)dx = 1 $

**Edit about possible duplicate**

Instead of going through all the calculations to find the pdf of $Y$, it's more elegant to come up with a 1-line solution based on correct reasoning about the problem.

Comment: Multiply factor is 2 not 1/2.

Comment: you're right, it's $2$. My bad.

Comment: @VictorS. Any further questions? Edit: Your edit is not clear. You have no doubt that a one line solution is not possible? Mmh...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{Y\leq y\}=\mathbb P\{-y\leq X\leq y\}.$$